# analysing fft of mp3 file in java

Tags: java, codenameone

I got these FFT algorithm in java here 
http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~ronw/code/MEAPsoft/doc/html/FFT_8java-source.html and another one here
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/FFT.java.html

However, I will like to use them in analysing mp3 file in other to plot some graphical representation of them probably in sin wave among others graphical representation.
My question is how can I pass my mp3 files to any of these algorithm to compute my fft for me. All I know is how to retrieve my mp3 file as byte array. However, AudioInputStream won't work in my use case as I have being such implementation.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a problem since you will need to author your own MP3 decoder logic in order to do something like this. The current media API's are implemented deep in the native code and can't expose the decoded media stream to user code.

Your other alternative is to write that portion of the code natively for each platform which shouldn't be very hard when using native interfaces: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

Comment: I have similar project, get FFT data from MP3 and use the data to create animation.         https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Spectrum-Analyser-Tutorials  this looks promising